# Suppose $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent. Prove $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n$ is absolutely convergent if $|b_n| \leq |a_n|$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

I am having a bit of trouble with this proof and I am not exactly sure how to prove it.

> Suppose $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent. Prove $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n$ is absolutely convergent if $|b_n| \leq |a_n|$ for all $n \geq 1$.

I started the question by using the Ratio Test, and by definition, the series is absolutely convergent if $\displaystyle \left|\dfrac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}\right| < 1$.

So if $\displaystyle \left|\dfrac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}\right| < 1$, then this means that
\begin{equation*}
|a_{n + 1}| < |a_n|
\end{equation*}

I am not exactly sure how to proceed from here. I would appreciate some help and advice.

Comment: Use the comparison test on $\sum |a_n|$ and $\sum |b_n|$.

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following :

We have that $|b_n|\leq|a_n|$ for every $n\geq1$. So let us take the partial sums
$\sum_{j=1}^{k}|a_j|$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{k}|b_j|$. We have :

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k}|b_j|\leq\sum_{j=1}^{k}|a_j|$$

for every $k\geq1$. The sequence $\sum_{j=1}^{k}|a_j|$ is an increasing sequence and since $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j$ is absolutely convergent, $\sum_{j=1}^{k}|a_j|$ converges to the upper bound of it's terms. Now we have :

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k}|b_j|\leq\sum_{j=1}^{k}|a_j|\leq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_j|$$

with $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_j|=a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{k}|b_j|$ being an increasing sequence with $a$ as it's upper bound. The rest follows.